# Is there a way to detect when DropDownButton closes?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to know when a `DropDownButton` closes its items? I know that there's an `onChanged` parameter but that only gets called when you select something from the items. I want to be able to know if the user just taps outside of the dropdown and closes the items.

**My Dropdown**

```dart
DropdownButton(
  isDense: true,
  isExpanded: true,
  value: _currentSelected,
  iconSize: 16,
  underline: const SizedBox.shrink(),
  style: _determineTextStyle(),
  hint: _hintText(),
  icon: _dropDownIcon(),
  items: listItems,
  onChanged: widget.isDisabled
      ? null
      : (value) async {
          await widget.onValueChanged(value as String);
        },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you wrap your dropDown inside a DropDownButtonFormField, you will get more options, and it will solve your problem.

Here is a working code I just tried it and modified it to fit your question.
You can do wonders in the input [decoration: InputDecoration()]

```
 DropdownButtonFormField(
   onTap: () => print('tapped open'),//THIS IS WHAT YOU NEED, IT WORKS ON TAPPING THE DROPDOWN
   isDense: true,
   isExpanded: true,
   iconSize: 16,                  
   validator: (dynamic value) => value.isEmpty ? _validatorText : null,
   decoration: InputDecoration(
        icon: Icon(Icons.category),
        labelText: "ENTER_LABELS_HERE", 
        ),
   items: listItems.map((label) => DropdownMenuItem(
   onTap: () => print('tapped single entry'),//THIS WORK WHEN TAPPING A SINGLE ENTRY FROM THE DROPDOWN
   child: Text('${LABEL_WHATEVER_VALUES_YOU_ARE_STORING IN THEM}'),
   value: label.ID,//ID is only an example, you can pass whatever you need here.
  )).toList(),
  onChanged: widget.isDisabled
  ? null
   : (value) async {
    await widget.onValueChanged(value as String);
    },
 );
```

Comment: No it didn't but I changed the way I handled it. Sadly I still didn't find a way to detect when you tap out of the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You can use the onTap property in [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html).It will be called when the user taps on the dropdown button.

```
DropdownButton(
  onTap: (){
    print('pressed');
  },
  isDense: true,
  isExpanded: true,
  value: _currentSelected,
  iconSize: 16,
  underline: const SizedBox.shrink(),
  style: _determineTextStyle(),
  hint: _hintText(),
  icon: _dropDownIcon(),
  items: listItems,
  onChanged: widget.isDisabled
      ? null
      : (value) async {
          await widget.onValueChanged(value as String);
        },
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the Dropdown widget with an inkwell widget

Comment: Might you explain a little more how this solves the problem, ideally with a code example?